# Any advice on simplifying this nasty integral

Tags: integration

Can anyone think of any smart way of approximating this nasty integral
$$F = \int_{-c}^c f_X(x) \, dx $$

where $c$ is a non-negative constant (for example $\frac{1}{64}$) and where the integrand is given by

$$f_X(x)= \int_{\max\{-1,-1-x\}}^{\min\{1,1-x\}} \left( \frac{1}{\pi^2\sqrt{1-(x+y)^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right) \, dy$$

I would really like to avoid numerical integration. Can anyone think of any simplifications that can reduce the complexity of my problem.

Please read comments below on why I have such a problem in the first place...

Thanks

Comment: How does it arise? Maybe it can be avoided and computed another way. It *does* look painful.

Comment: The function $f_X(x)$is the probability density function of  $X=\cos(U)-\cos(V)$ where $U,V$ are uniform random variables. The reason I am integrating $F$ is because I had a function of this random variable $X$ and I had to take the expectation with respect to it.... does that make any sense? @MPW

Comment: I should say $U,V\sim [-\pi,\pi]$...

Comment: So is the question really "what is the expected value of $\cos U +\cos V$ where $U$ and $V$ are independent random variables uniformly distributed on $[-\pi,\pi]$?"?

Comment: No the function that I had to average (take the expectation over) was $\mathbb{E}[G(X)]$ where $G(x)= 1, -c\leq x\leq c$. and 0 everywhere else, this is why I have $F$ in this form shown above..@MPW

Comment: Maple and WolframAlpha can calculate the indefinite integral; they give an answer using an elliptic function.

Comment: @BernardMassé thanks, do you mean by indefinite integral $f_X(x)$?

Comment: @MPW i have already found the distribution of $X=\cos(U)-\cos V$, then I took an expectation of a piecewise function of $X$...

Comment: @Henry Yes the integral without bounds.

Comment: can you take the answer and put the bounds that I have here and still have the right answer? @BernardMassé.... also can you please show me how one can write it wolfram alpha..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer provides the result in terms of a convergent series in Eq. (1).

The inner integral can be solved explicitly in terms of [the complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2) with the result (valid for $|x|<2$)
$$ f_X(x) = \frac1{\pi^2} K\Bigl(\sqrt{1-x^2/4}\Bigr) = \frac{1}{\pi^2}K'(|x|/2).$$

Using the expansion of $K$ around 1, we can obtain the expression
$$ F= \frac{2 c \log(2^3e/c)}{\pi^2} + \frac{c^3 \log(2^9/e^2 c^3)}{72 \pi^2} + O(c^5 \log c)$$
valid for $c\ll1$.

In fact using the formula [19.12.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.12), the integral $F$ can be obtained as a convergent series. Indeed, we have that
$$K'(k)= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\left(\tfrac12\right)_m k^m}{m!}\right)^2  \left[\log(1/k) + d(m)\right] $$
for $k<1$ with $d(m)= \psi(1+m) - \psi(1/2 +m)$; here, $\psi$ is the digamma function and $(a)_n =\Gamma(a+n)/\Gamma(a)$ the Pochhammer symbol.

Integrating $F= \int_{-c}^c f_X(x)$ term by term yields
$$ F= \frac{1}{\pi^2} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\left(\tfrac12\right)_m }{m!}\right)^2  \frac{c^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)2^{2m-1}} \left[\frac{1 + (2m+1) \log(2/c)}{2m+1} + d(m)\right] \tag{1},$$
where we have used that $$\int_{-c}^c \!dx\,x^{2m}= \frac{2 c^{2m+1}}{2m+1}$$ and
$$\int_{-c}^c\!dx\,x^{2m}\log(1/x) = \frac{2 c^{2m+1} [1 + (2m+1) \log(1/c)]}{(2m+1)^2}.$$

A special point occurs at $c=2$ where the logarithmic terms in (1) vanish and we simply obtain
$F(c=2) = 1$.

*Edit:*
Following the [general procedure](http://everything2.com/title/elliptic+integral+standard+forms) and specifying $0<x<1$ (it can be checked that the result remains unmodified in the other cases), we factor
$$(1- (x+y)^2)(1-y^2) =(1-y) (1-x-y) (y+1)(y+1+x) .$$
This leads to the substitution $$
t= \sqrt{\frac{2 (1+y)}{(2-x)(1+x+y)}}.$$
Via this substitution the boundaries $y=-1$ and $y=1-x$ are transformed to $t=0$ and $t=1$ and we obtain
$$\int_{-1}^{1-x}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1- (x+y)^2)(1-y^2)}}
= \int_0^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)[1-(1-x^2/4) t^2]}}$$
which is the standard form of the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: wow impressive can you please provide more details....i dont understand how you were able to do it

Comment: @Henry: Of course it is not the first time, I have solved an ellliptic integral... ;-)

Comment: thank you. If you dont mind i want to ask : what to do you mean by expansion of $K $ around 1. Also why did you take x between 0 and 1... in my case its between -1 and 1. Thanks

Comment: @Henry: you have to treat the cases $x<-1$, $-1<x<0$, $0<x<1$, $x>1$ differently as they ask for different substitutions. It turns out that they all the cases lead to the result quoted in particular it is not difficult to convince yourself that $x$ and $-x$ lead to the same result.

Comment: thank you and i agree.. cam you please tell me how you got the expansiom aroung $K=1$us that an approximation?

Comment: The expansion around $k=1$ you can find [here (19.12.1)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.12). Note that by definition $k'= \sqrt{1-k^2}$. In principle, you can obtain term by term and obtain a convergent series in $c$ for your integral. The approximation, I have given is reasonably accurate up to $c \simeq 2$. I will add the complete answer as well.

Comment: this work is fabulous can I ask is the $\log$ in your answer base what? and why is it that the expansion is only valid for $c<<<1$?

Comment: @Henry: it is the natural logarithm.

Comment: Is the expansion only valid for very small positive $c$?

Comment: It is valid up to $c=2$.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, for $$G(x) = \mathbb{1}(|x|\le c) = \begin{cases} 1, & -c \le x \le c \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ we then simply have $$\mathbb E[G(X)] = \Pr[|X| \le c].$$  If $X = \cos U - \cos V$ where $U, V \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(?,?)$ are independent, then you need to specify the support of the uniform distribution before we can proceed further.

Comment: Thanks, the support of $U,V \sim U(-\pi,\pi)$, for which I think the distribution of $X$ is $f_X(x)$ in my question....